# Exception on new WebView on Lollipop 5.1 devices

Tags: java, android, webview

I try add WebView to my activity:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
```

On all devices this work fine, but on Android Lollipop 5.1 (only) devices I got exception in this line:

```
10-18 12:04:29.741 13131-13131/xx.xxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xx.xxxxxx, PID: 13131
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xx.xxxxxx/xx.xxxxxx.activity.login.UseActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040003
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040003
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:385)
        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.setContainerView(ContentViewCore.java:684)
        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.initialize(ContentViewCore.java:608)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.createAndInitializeContentViewCore(AwContents.java:631)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.setNewAwContents(AwContents.java:780)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:619)
        at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:556)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.initForReal(WebViewChromium.java:311)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.access$100(WebViewChromium.java:96)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:263)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.drainQueue(WebViewChromium.java:123)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:110)
        at com.android.org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(ThreadUtils.java:144)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.addTask(WebViewChromium.java:107)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:260)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:554)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:489)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:472)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:459)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:449)
        at xx.xxxxxx.activity.login.UseActivity.onActivityCreate(UseActivity.java:69)
        at xx.xxxxxx.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:148)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

What I'm doing wrong and what is best way for solution on Android Lollipop 5.1 devices.

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException`

Comment: yes, but why exceptions only on 5.1 devices (probably 5.1 with not installed Google Play Services or not-registered Google account on deveice)?

Comment: share your UseActivity & BaseActivity code

Comment: check google ps is present or not

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, not possible at moment, this is on productions users without stats, probably in future I'll try add check google play services status

Comment: @Mike M., yes, creating WebView throught inflating call exception like in your link too. Seems like 5.1 WebView implementation have bug.

Comment: @Mike M., add '<string name="accessibility_content_view">Web View</string>' to my strings not work for me, sorry. Need some manipulations with 'R' probably

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, that shouldn't work, 'cause the identifier - which is just an `int` - that's compiled into that `WebView` component is going to be completely different than what an identifier in your app would end up being. Sorry 'bout that. I should've thought of that to begin with.

Answer (score 9):

This can be fixed by catching the error, and then creating the WebView with the Application context instead:

```
try {
    webView = new WebView(this);
}
catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
    // Some older devices can crash when instantiating a WebView, due to a Resources$NotFoundException
    // Creating with the application Context fixes this, but is not generally recommended for view creation
    webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Creating Views with the Application context is generally discouraged, but is an OK fallback here.

Comment: Did you find an actual solution for this ? I have a pretty big branch and on that branch webview on 5.1 doesn't work. Whereas my master branch works just fine. I have nothing changed in manifest/build gradle

Comment: @ronocod Do you have any reference for this?